# How to zero out values that are less than median in each row?

Tags: python, numpy

```
A = numpy.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [5,4,1]])
```

I want to compute median of each row and then zero out all values that are less than the median. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [5,4,1]])
medians=np.median(A,axis=1)[np.newaxis].T
A[A<medians]=0

A=
 [[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [5 4 1]]

Medians=
 [[ 1.]
 [ 4.]
 [ 4.]]

A after subtracting medians
 [[0 1 2]
 [0 4 5]
 [5 4 0]]
```